# Having an issue with diacritics and Solr Search

Tags: c#, .net, solr

I am working with a dot NET MVC application and with an Apache Solr. I have two fields indexed into Solr, one is Name & second is Category. I have indexed some diacritics words in Name as well as in Category field with this encoding method.

> HttpUtility.UrlEncode()

The reason I have index it with encoding is that I want to display Category with Facets.

So all this values are indexed in encoded form into Solr. Now, during Search process I am encoding searchterm and then searching it into Solr and it gives me result.

But the problem is that if I search the same word without diacritic, it does not give me any result as the word is stored into encoded form.

Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field `category_norm` and add a normalizing analyzer chain to it (I think the example schema has one for text), then use a `copyField` to automatically copy the content from your `category` into the new field.

Or you could turn it around and introduce `category_facet` for faceting with the raw value and let the field `name` have the search-version, again using `copyField` to keep them synchronized.

Comment: I have already copy field with text type. But it will copy the same value as in the default field. For example,  prótese is indexed after encoding like: pr%c3%b3tese in main field as well as in Copy field. Now I am not able to search with Protese word.

Comment: Have you reviewed my previous comment?